# Collapsing data in SAS with PROC SQL

Tags: group-by, sas, proc-sql

I've been trying unsuccesfully for sometime now to collapse a data set using a `PROC SQL` with `GROUPBY` and was wondering if I could get some help. Here is an example of what I am trying to do. Suppose we have the following data:

```
id   year  parent_id  age
"01" 1990    "23"      17
"01" 1991    "23"      18
"01" 1992    "23"      19
"02" 1978    "18"      24
"02" 1979    "18"      25
```

that we wanted to collapse by `id` preserving the row with the `min` `age` across years to get the following dataset

```
id   year   parent_id   age
"01" 1990   "23"        17
"02" 1978   "18"        24
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE output_tablename as
       SELECT DISTINCT id, year, parent_id, min(age) as age
       FROM input_tablename
       GROUPBY id;
quit;
```

to no avail.

Comment: Using a `data` step here would be easy. For `proc sql`, you could join the `year` and `parent_id` after the `min(age)` calculation on `id` and `age`. something like -  `proc sql;
create table output_tablename as
select a.*, b.year, b.parent_id 
from (
select id, min(age) as age
from input_tablename
group by id) a
left join input_tablename b
on a.id=b.id and a.age=b.age;
quit;`

Comment: What does *to no avail* mean? What is the error or undesired result? Why not minimize all values except the grouping variable, *id*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was getting duplicate results in my output dataset but I think this was actually a result of another mistake. However, the alternate methods suggested are very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HAVING clause to pick only records where age = min(age).

```
   proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   group by ID
   having age=min(age);
   quit;
```

PROC SORT option:

```
proc sort data=have; by id descending age;
run; 
proc sort data=have nodupkey out=want; 
by id;
run;
```